# How do I infer the exact type of an object function parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object with properties that are typed using a generic template literal that requires a certain provided (as the generic type parameter) substring to be present in the string.
Currently, if an invalid value is provided, the error is that the value cannot be assigned to the template literal.

I would like to make it so that the error message includes a type with custom message.
E.g. `Type 'never' is not assignable to type 'ErrorMessage<"You cannot do that.">'.`
I have seen libraries that do this, but I am not sure how to do it in this case.
I have a generic that creates this, but it when trying get it all to work with objects, the properties are not narrow enough.

I have worked up to the following:

```
interface ErrorMessage<T> {
  __msg: T;
}

type Substring<
  str extends string,
  substr extends string
> = str extends `${string}${substr}${string}`
  ? str
  : ErrorMessage<`No match: '${str}' does not contain '${substr}'`>;

type Substrings = {
  bar: "aaa";
};

type Foo<T extends { [K in keyof Substrings]: string }> = {
  [K in keyof T & keyof Substrings]: Substring<T[K], Substrings[K]>;
};

type Infer<T extends { [K in keyof Substrings]: string }> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

const helper =
  <T extends { [K in keyof Substrings]: string }>(val: Infer<T>) =>
  (val2: Foo<T>) =>
    val2;

const foo = helper({
  bar: "has bar aaa",
})({
  bar: "has bar aaa",
});
```

This works in theory, but the duplicate function call is awkward.
Is there any way I can make `helper` "self-contained"?
Every other variation I have tried ends up with the property types of the object being inferred as just `string`.
The main issue being that TypeScript can't infer `T` for `helper` when using a generic that otherwise works.

I could pass the type parameter, but that requires defining the object separately `as const` and then using `typeof`, which is also quite awkward.

As a slightly different approach, the following almost works, except for `K` not being a valid index of `Substrings` in the mapping in `Foo`:

```
type Foo<T extends { [K in keyof T & keyof Substrings]: string }> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Substring<T[K], Substrings[K]>;
};

const helper = <T extends { [K in keyof Substrings]: string }>(val: Foo<T>) =>
  val;
```

I may have gone up a dead end with this particular approach. If you know or can figure out a different way, I'm happy with that. I have no special affinity for what I've got at the moment, it's just what I've ended up on so far.

I have a feeling there will be some function overloads and currying involved, but I'm not proficient enough to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

**Update: plain example with regular error messages:**

```
type Substring<substr extends string> = `${string}${substr}${string}`;

type Substrings = {
  bar: "aaa";
};

type Foo<T extends { [key: string]: string }> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Substring<T[K]>;
};

const helper = <T extends Foo<Substrings>>(val: T) => val;

const foo = helper({
  bar: "has bar aaa",
});
```

Comment: Could you show the simple version that works how you want except that you don't love the error message?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr4gDW) work for you?  Please test against your use cases.  If it works I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that does work pretty much as expected. So the solution is to basically remove any use of generics, so that TS can infer properly?

Comment: As a bonus, any way to have a nice error for missing properties? The solution you gave gives "`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ErrorMessage<`No match: '${string}' does not contain 'aaa'`>'. The expected type comes from property 'bar' which is declared here on type '{ bar: ErrorMessage<`No match: '${string}' does not contain 'aaa'`>; baz: ErrorMessage<`No match: '${string}' does not contain 'bbb'`>; }'". cc @jcalz

Comment: I don't understand  "remove any use of generics" since my proposed solution is a generic helper function.  What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I put that really badly. I meant _use of named generic types in the function signature_, such as `Substring`. @jcalz

Comment: Is the scope of the question expanding?  It seems you are now asking me to figure out specifically why your original version isn't working, and also make a better error message for missing properties.  For the missing properties one, maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/mM1ozm)?  For the named generic type issue, the details of inference failure are fiddly; the added indirection probably causes the type to fall back to the constraint completely, but I can't be sure and... well it seems out of scope for the question as asked. I'd love to write up an answer but I'm worried about scope.

Comment: Sorry for going on and on with more questions, @jcalz. Looking at it now, I see I am most definitely allowing scope creep. Ignore the missing properties thing and don't worry about an explanation of the guts of type parameter inference. Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Okay I wrote up an answer.  I did briefly look into the issue with using named type aliases inside the helper function and it looks like the inference only works as desired when `T[K] extends ...` appears directly.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP9oKw), which allows you to use your type alias, but it's redundant.  I couldn't refactor it into a single use of the alias without losing the inference you care about.  Oh well!

Comment: I wonder if TS 5's `const` parameter modifier affects this at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
const helper = <T extends Record<keyof Substrings, string>>(
    t: { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof Substrings ? (
        T[K] extends `${string}${Substrings[K]}${string}` ?
        T[K] : ErrorMessage<`No match: '${T[K]}' does not contain '${Substrings[K]}'`>
    ) : T[K] }
) => t;
```

The algorithm the type checker uses when inferring [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters is a bit fiddly.  The compiler is pretty good about inferring from homomorphic [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), meaning that it can often infer `T` from the type `{[K in keyof T]: ...T[K]...}`.  But the particular place `T[K]` appears in that `...T[K]...` has a lot to do with how successful the inference will be.

One rule of thumb I use is that if you want the compiler to infer a generic `X` from a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), you should make sure that `X` appears directly as the checked type, like `X extends ... ? ... : ...`.  Since we want the compiler to infer `T[K]`, then we want `T[K] extends ...` directly.  Hence the `` T[K] extends `${string}${Substrings[K]}${string}` ? ... `` type.  You *might* be able to refactor this into its own named type alias, but this could have strange add-on effects I don't want to get into here.

---

Anyway, let's test it:

```
const foo1 = helper({
    bar: "has bar aaa",
}); // okay

const foo2 = helper({
    bar: "oopsie doodle" // error!
    //~ <-- 'ErrorMessage<"No match: 'oopsie doodle' does not contain 'aaa'">'
})
```

Looks good.  You get the error message you're looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgIwM7AE4EsB2BzJUC8UA3gFBTlQICGqAXFAERXMMDcJAvuyVsBKgDMqAY2gBRVKgD2qALIQkSKtggAeACoA+YmQoB9PQFsk2euvYcSJYVMwooACwgAbSKgJQNUCAA8+mABM8ACUIG1QA1QBrCBApAVhEFAwcJAAaKGSsbE1NAApdcmB6IigAbQBpKCwoGLiE9QBdeirffyDa2PjE5DRsvAB+KAKKUah1SsbvPwhAvAADABIiLJwOZfhelNxJ9ZW+tfmoAcKxiYqp+glpOQUlFVV5gDkpKEMqYGEHegByZfPGhwflAAlIFFBMFJgFAbJhgFQan8iJtVjsLkD5ppTgBKKBmSZQSy4-DaYDcay2ewCKRSACMHicrn4eVIo2odEYDioeHZUGYVAYaU42NYUAA9GKoFIolQQFZYVSaQAmBkuNws07s+gMGlgJDoaCgqQBZwQBjiyX8G4AQlOEoAfp4ALROqA-a4yeSKZRqBgvN4fL6-XX6w00k0QYGg8GQ6Gw+GI-k-BiaH7CqxAA)